# How to make regular expression for ("1:2,2.2,3:4,4.1,5") in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making webpage with `AngularJS`.

I want to filter `<input>` tag. So `<input>` tag can only accept special formula.
Here is formula and code I've tried.

**Formula:**

```
1.1, 2, 3:4, 3:6, 1.3
```

**Code**

```
function processExpression(expression) {
   let expression = expression.replace(/\s+/g, '');

   if (!/^\d+(?::\d+)?(?:,\d+(?::\d+)?)*$/.test(expression)) {
     // fail case
     return false;
   }

   // success case
   return true;
}
```

My current code works without dot(`.`) now. For example `1:2, 3, 4, 5`

But it doesn't works for dot(`.`). For example `1:2, 3.1, 4, 5.1, 6`

How can I do it? Please anyone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to specify both `:` and `.` as a separator:

```
/^\d+(?:[:.]\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:[:.]\d+)?)*$/
```